# Ubuntu 12.04 not recognizing my 4 tb hdd

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive

I am using a SSD as the main hard drive and want to use my 4tb hdd as a storage drive. However, I can't find it in Ubuntu. I checked the bios, and it is known.

edit

```
Disk /dev/sda: 240.1 GB, 240057409536 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 29185 cylinders, total 468862128 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00048cf8

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   435378175   217688064   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       435380222   468860927    16740353    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       435380224   468860927    16740352   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 4000.8 GB, 4000787030016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486401 cylinders, total 7814037168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdc: 8019 MB, 8019509248 bytes
20 heads, 16 sectors/track, 48947 cylinders, total 15663104 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *          80    15663103     7831512    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 17.1 GB, 17142120448 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2084 cylinders, total 33480704 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xf3c5ebb4

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Comment: What is the outout of command `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: IF it is 4TB, fdisk will not work as it has to be gpt partitioned and fdisk is for MBR(msdos) partitioned drives. You can use parted or gdisk but have to install gdisk from Software Center, synaptic or command line. 'sudo parted -l'

Comment: I tried downloading the gdisk, but how do I make it work?